# Do wires need covering when plastering?

Tags: wiring, plaster

Many places say that you need to cover wires when plastering over them:

[theiet.org/forum](http://www.theiet.org/forums/forum/messageview.cfm?catid=205&threadid=11645)

> In a zone or not I would still steel cap the cables even if they were only TV Aerial cables.

and this

> IMO PVC capping is safer, as long as it's in the zone, as there is no chance of it becoming live.

and

> If clipping direct to a wall then reasonable protection is needed from the plasterers trowel.

There is [diynot.com/forums](http://www.diynot.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=185342):

> Capping of any sort is not required by the regs

and finally this

> Nothing wrong with plastering directly over the cables though. As said, the capping was more to prevent damage during plastering and although there is no direct mention if this in the regs, it was the intended purpose.

So some say that it is needed, some say it is worthless... Who is right? Do I need to cap the wires?

Comment: You really should note your location so that you get the correct regs and codes for your area.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, the capping was used to protect cables from being sliced by a plasterer's trowel when wet plastering over them.

For the (nominal) cost of them, I'd use capping if the wall was to be wet plastered. (Plus, though it's not always easy, it does give you a chance to re-cable if that ever becomes required in the future).

If the wall was to be dry lined, I'd just clip the cables to the wall.

According to the wiring "regulations", capping is not sufficiently robust mechanical protection to avoid the need for RCD protection to the circuit.